# Using webservice in Qt

Tags: asp.net, web-services, qt, parsing, soap

I was surfing through various article related to Webservice in Qt , but unfortunatly didn't got what i was looking for. I am using .Net webservice with SOAP, and want to parse this service. Gone through various related article, but the basic problem that i am facing is to get the Soap libraries? Where to download from? And how to integrate? And this will really work for me?

Thank You.

Comment: The cynic's response to this is... "Welcome to SOAP".  Seriously, you'll have to look for, and review several different SOAP libraries and pick the best one that fits your particular purpose.  They will each have rather significant drawbacks and compatibility issues.

Comment: Also, which version of Qt? (Qt itself seems to have some SOAP support)

Comment: Thanks guys i think i have figured it out....will post here soon..

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably integrating [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) into your Qt application. (Make sure it's [Licensing](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soaplicense.html) terms are ok for you.)

A good run-down of how to do the integration is [GSoap: SAOP and XML Web services for Qt apps](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/GSoap%3a_SOAP_and_XML_Web_services_for_Qt_apps) (includes a sample .zip file). That doesn't require a specific version of Qt (since gSOAP is doing all the work essentially), so anything modern-ish should do.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot....i will go through this and let you know if any problem occur ....hope you dont mind with this..

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a very late suggestion, [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) is a free/open source software SOAP stack that appears to fit your needs.